# How to set and use a variable from an array value in a DOS/Windows batch file

Tags: batch, array

In a DOS/Windows batch file, how can I set/use a variable from an array and a loop index, such that I can produce output like what's shown below?

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set x[0]=one
set x[1]=two
set x[2]=three
for %%i in (0,1,3) do (
    call set y=%x[%%i]%
    echo y=%y%
)


DESIRED OUTPUT:
    y=one
    y=two
    y=three
```

What I'm really trying to do is repeatedly call a program and pass a bunch of parameters, one of which is an array variable. If I replace the [%%i] on the line with call set, with [0], the output when that line is executed is "call set y=one" as expected. But if I use [%%i] to access the array element the output changes to "call set y=". I've tried so many combinations of ways to do this, and none produce the desired result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I set/use a variable from an array and a loop index?

You have the right idea with your code but your are missing some of the details required for it to work correctly.

The following will do what you want (test.cmd)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set x[0]=one
set x[1]=two
set x[2]=three
for %%i in (0,1,2) do (
    set y=!x[%%i]!
    echo y=!y!
)
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
F:\test>test
y=one
y=two
y=three
F:\test>
```

Notes:

- `for` should be `for /l` but it seems the `/l` is optional as it work without it.
- Your `for` loop end value should have been `2` not `3`.
- You declared `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` correctly but did not replace `%` with `!` where appropriate.
- You don't need `call` before `set`.
- You didn't end your script with `endlocal` so your variable will "leak" into the parent cmd shell.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [Endlocal - Local environment variables - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)
- [For /l - Loop through a range of numbers - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)

Comment: Thank you so much... that does indeed work. Now to study what you did and see if I can learn something.

Comment: @funbotix: Why not mark as answer if the guy answered your question right?

Comment: Thanks... I intended to mark the answer as correct, but I had not yet figured out how to do that yet. Fortunately... Google had the answer to that question ;) Thanks @DavidPostill