# Trying to Echo Array Values by Referencing the Array.Length Variable

Tags: windows, batch, script, code

I'm trying to output the contents of an array index # by referencing the index # using the **A1.length** value. But since I still don't fully understand the expansion of variables, the most I get for output is either the ***actual length value*** or the **string** ***A1.length.***

- For clarification:

```
A1 = The Array
A1.length = 1
A1[1] = Superuser
```

The `%~1` arguments in my examples below are passing the array name
`A1`.

I posted the code at the bottom that plainly shows the failed results at echoing the value `Superuser` or any actual values from any of the array indexes. I only get the `index #` or the literal string `A1.length`, UNLESS I use a workaround, which requires a temp variable.

I can get it to work by creating a temp variable to reference `A1.length`, like so, but is this required:

```
set temp=!%~1.length!
echo !%~1[%temp%]!
```

This outputs the actual content/value of each index in the A1 array, and works for what I need it to do. But is a temp variable actually required to do this?

Also, why does the 1st echo work, but not the 2nd echo?

```
echo 1. Output: !%~1[%A1.length%]!
echo 2. Output: !%~1[%~1.length]!
```

The 1st one parses the statement correctly, though I had to convert the inner argument `%~1` to its actual value: `A1`

While the 2nd one parses the statement as `!A1[A1.length]!`, which looks like it just needs to maybe be expanded one more time, but is that even possible?
Will the added exclamation marks allow for additional expansion. I thought using exclamation marks always expand variables to their topmost or last level value.

Anyhow, I added `CALL` to the 2nd `ECHO`, and as expected, it had the same output.

- Here are a few things I have tried:

```
echo 1.Output: !%~1[%~1.length]!
:: Parsed as: !A1[A1.length]!
:: Output as: 
   
call echo 2.Output: !%~1[%~1.length]!
:: Parsed as: !A1[A1.length]!
:: Output as: 
    
echo 3.Output: %~1[%%~1.length%]
:: Parsed as: A1[%~1.length]
:: Output as: A1[%~1.length]

echo 4.Output: %%%~1[%~1.length]%%%
:: Parsed as: %A1[A1.length]%
:: Output as: %A1[A1.length]%

call echo 4b.Output: %%%~1[%~1.length]%%%
:: Parsed as: %A1[A1.length]%
:: Output as: 

echo 5.Output: %~1[%~1.length]
:: Parsed as: A1[A1.length]
:: Output as: A1[A1.length]

echo 6.Output: %%~1[%~1.length]%%
:: Parsed as: %~1[A1.length]%
:: Output as: %~1[A1.length]%

call echo 6b.Output: %%~1[%~1.length]%%
:: Parsed as: %~1[A1.length]%
:: Output as: A1[A1.length]

echo 7.Output: !%~1[!%%~1.length%!]!
:: Parsed as: !A1[!%~1.length!]!
:: Output as: A1.length

call echo 8.Output: %%~1[%%~1.length]%%
:: Parsed as: %~1[%~1.length]%
:: Output as: A1[A1.length]
```

What am I missing or forgetting? Why can't I get it to `echo` the value `Superuser` from the array? Is it required to use a temp variable for `ECHO` to echo the value of an array?

- Here is the code that demonstrates the issue:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

call :array-append A1 "Superuser"

goto :eof

:array-append <1=ArrayName> <2=Value> <3=Value>
    :array-append-repeat
    set %~1.length=1
    set %~1[!%~1.length!]=%~2
    :: call set %~1[%%%~1.length%%]=%~2
    echo Length=[!%~1.length!]
    
    :: Worker variable works!
    echo.&echo Using a worker variable, the following output is correct:
    set temp=!%~1.length!
    echo %~1[!%~1[%temp%]!]
    
    echo.&echo Attempting to directly ECHO the value of A1.Length
    echo None of the following works...what am I doing wrong?
    echo.
    
    echo !%~1[%~1.length]!
    :: Output> ECHO is off.
    
    echo %~1[!%~1.length!]
    :: Output> A1[1] 
    
    call echo %~1[%%%~1.length%%]
    :: Output> A1[1
    
    echo !%~1[!%~1.length!]!
    :: Output> A1.length
    
    :: call set %~1[%%%~1.length%%]=%~2
    set /a %~1.length+=1
    shift /2
    
    goto :eof
```

Comment: It'd be a good idea to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1774173/edit) the question and add the complete script you currently use.

Comment: It essentially just comes down to using the correct variable expansion symbols to echo the value of the Array index, which in my case is Array=A1, Index=length (let's say length=1) and Value=Superuser. Using any of the example statements I provided in my post, why can't I get the value Superuser to echo?

Comment: Dunno mate, and can't test as you don't provide an example script...

Comment: Does [How to set and use a variable from an array value in a DOS/Windows batch file - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1703260/how-to-set-and-use-a-variable-from-an-array-value-in-a-dos-windows-batch-file/1703266#1703266) andswer your question?

Comment: I have added code that demonstrates the specific issue I'm having. I'm currently trying to learn and understand how two-level variable expansion in batch works, but I'm obviously still not grasping some of the fundamentals. Any suggestions for additional reading will be appreciated!